# TikZ - Proper obscuring of objects in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf

When drawing in TikZ in 3D, is there any way for objects behind to be properly obscured by those in front, as they would appear if actually viewed in 3D?

For example:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,fill=gray!50](0,0)rectangle(2,4);
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=2,->](-2,1)--(2,1);
  \node at (0,3) {This\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=2](-2,1)--(0,1);
  \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,fill=gray!50](0,0)rectangle(2,4);
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=2,->](0,1)--(2,1);
  \node at (0,3) {\ldots should look like this};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should draw the objects as you see them; in the example, the segment should be split in two, the portion you see and the portion you don't see completely.  Then you should draw them the latter first, the plane, and the former.  You can also look at the use of layers, but at the end, the segment must be split.

Comment: @Daniel N That's kind of what I was thinking, I was just hoping that there was a more "automatic" way to do that.